# Disable MySQL startup in Linux

Tags: mysql, manjaro, mariadb

I have KDE, and it has software to manage startup packages. But, I don't see any `mysql`, `mariaDB` or `mysqld` service.

How can I disable or prevent the `mariaDB` and `mysql` daemons from starting automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on systemd (default on Arch) then that would be

```
systemctl disable mysqld.service
```